# Mysql select statement

Tags: sql, mysql

I need a proper way to write a simple WHERE, AND, OR statement.  This one doesn't work:

```
SELECT `content` 
  FROM `bx_wall_events` 
 WHERE `type` = 'wall_common_text' 
    OR `type` = 'wall_common_fb' 
    OR `type`= 'wall_common_tw' 
   AND `owner_id`='{$iId}' 
ORDER BY `date` DESC 
   LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a valid statement, but I imagine the issue is the ORs aren't being interpreted like you'd expect.  Use the IN syntax instead:

```
  SELECT content
    FROM bx_wall_events
   WHERE `type` IN ('wall_common_text', 'wall_common_fb', 'wall_common_tw')
     AND `owner_id` = '{$iId}' 
ORDER BY `date` DESC 
   LIMIT 1
```

I removed the backticks in certain spots because they're only necessary for escaping table & column names that are using [MySQL reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html).

The way this:

```
WHERE `type` = 'wall_common_text' 
   OR `type` = 'wall_common_fb' 
   OR `type`= 'wall_common_tw' 
  AND `owner_id`='{$iId}'
```

...is evaluating is:

```
WHERE (`type` = 'wall_common_text')
   OR (`type` = 'wall_common_fb')
   OR (`type`= 'wall_common_tw' AND `owner_id`='{$iId}')
```

Comment: You can also just place parentheses around the ORs to separate them from the AND, but I do agree this is the way to go here.

Comment: @Michael Madsen: You can, but `IN` is more maintainable--miss or misplace one bracket, and the query can be valid but won't return correct data.  Miss a bracket on the `IN`, and you're guaranteed a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT `content` FROM `bx_wall_events` 
 WHERE ((`type`= 'wall_common_text') || (`type`= 'wall_common_fb') || (`type`= 'wall_common_tw')) 
 AND `owner_id`='{$iId}' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1"

Comment: In MySQL by default, || is a logical OR operator.  With PIPES_AS_CONCAT enabled, || is string concatenation (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operator-precedence.html)

Comment: @martin clayton: Didn't know that, but I did know that if you enable strict SQL then double pipes are for string concatenation...

Answer (score 0):

Found a great solution using the IN

```
"SELECT `content` 
FROM `bx_wall_events` 
WHERE `owner_id`='{$iId}' 
AND `type`
IN ('wall_common_text', 'wall_common_fb', 'wall_common_tw') 
ORDER BY `date` 
DESC LIMIT 1"
```